If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is monotone then it is Borel measurable
This question has been posted several times, but I have not seen any proof match mine. I am following Folland's text, and was wondering if my proof was valid (inspired by Folland's proof that the sgn function is Borel measurable).
Note that since $f$ is monotonic, the points (denoted by $P$) at which it is discontinuous is at most countable. Let U be an open set in $\mathbb R$, so $f^{-1}(U) = \{ x \in \mathbb R : f(x) \in U \} = \{x \in P : f(x) \in U \}\cup \{x \in \mathbb R\setminus P : f(x) \in U \}$.
The former is some subset of the countable union of points $ \cup_{p \in P} \{p\}$ which is clearly a Borel set, and for the latter since $f$ is continuous on $R \setminus P$ we can easily show that $\{x \in R \setminus P : f(x) \in U\}$ is open and therefore a Borel set.

Being continuous on $\mathbb R\setminus P$ means that set is open in $\mathbb R\setminus P.$ It doesn't mean it is open in $\mathbb R.$ Indeed, $P=\mathbb Q$ means no  non-empty subset of $\mathbb R\setminus P$ is open in $\mathbb R.$

If a function is monotonic, the preimage of intervals are also intervals.

This site is not a proof checking machine. Please check the [tag:solution-verification] tag description: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplication. For this reason I vote to close.

${x\in R \setminus P: f(x) \in U}$ is not open, at least not in the sense that you are using the word open.

If a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is monotonic, then either the preimage of an interval is an interval or its preimage is the empty set. Given that the Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is generated by intervals and the empty set is also measurable, then the function $f$ is measurable as well.
Hopefully this helps!

The problem is that $f^{-1}(U)\setminus P$ is not necessarily open in $\mathbb R,$ it is only open in $\mathbb R\setminus P.$
You can fix this argument, though.
What you can say is that $f^{-1}(U)\setminus P$ is open in $\mathbb R\setminus P,$ so there is an open set $V$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $$V\setminus P=V\cap(\mathbb R\setminus P)=f^{-1}(U)\setminus P.$$ Then $V\setminus (f^{-1}(U)\setminus P)\subseteq P$ is countable, so since $V$ is Borel, so is $f^{-1}(U)\setminus P.$
